# How does one list warnings from the 'mysqlimport' utility?

Tags: mysql, database, command-line-interface, import, csv

To start off, this is not about loading data from within MySQL itself, but using the command-line tool "mysqlimport".

I am using it to load a CSV directly into a table and need to see the warnings it has generated. I cannot seem to get warnings to display with verbose nor debugging turned on. Any ideas?

(MySQL 5.0.5)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's not possible with mysqlimport, however as an alternative you can do the following:

```
mysql --execute="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$WORKDIR/$table.csv' INTO TABLE $table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' IGNORE 1 LINES (listOfColumnNames); SHOW WARNINGS"
```

Replace `listOfColumnNames` with an appropriate seperated list of columns.

The magic is (as Eduard previously mentioned) is to execute the LOAD DATA INFILE and the SHOW WARNINGS commands together in the same session, as mysqlimport doesn't provide a way to get at the warnings directly.

Comment: Sweet, thank you! I had just begun writing a statement like this after seeing Eduard's comment. Thanks yo!

Thanks

Comment: Does this work if `tables.csv` is a local file (i.e., not on the server of the database)?

Comment: the following works for me create the table first then do   `mysql -u root --execute="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:\\crp\\blah3.csv' INTO TABLE blah3 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','; SHOW WARNINGS" whateverdbnameegcsv_db`  related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127529/mysql-import-data-from-csv-using-load-data-infile

Comment: and can add e.g. about utf8 `mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:\\crp\\blah5.csv' INTO TABLE blah5 CHARACTER SET UTF8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'; SHOW WARNINGS;` as mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957900/loading-utf-8-encoded-text-into-mysql-table

Comment: a problem is that the exit code is always `0` so I guess you have to parse the command output to check whether the import succeeded when the above is scripted (?)

Answer (score 5):

Like the others said the real problem is that for SHOW WARNINGS to work you have to be in the same connected session. mysqlimport disconnects from the session as soon as it's finished importing, making the capture of it's warnings impossible in it's current version. Sounds like an opportunity to donate a patch. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've found no way to print warnings with mysqlimport either. But since mysqlimport does nothing but "LOAD DATA INFILE" why don't you use the mysql command to import the data followed by a "SHOW WARNINGS"?

Comment: Thanks! Kind of irritating mysqlimport doesn't really play nice :/

Comment: Use the "SHOW WARNINGS;" command after "LOAD".