# about mysqlimport show warnings

Tags: mysql, import

i try to use mysql command to achieve show warnings after execution
but my command seems didn't work,what's wrong with the below code,i have tested for many times

```
mysql -uroot -pbin \W --execute="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/mlzboy/code/mq/model_product.csv' INTO TABLE search.model_product FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (name,price,productid,site,link,smallImage,bigImage,description,createdOn,modifiedOn,size,weight,wrap,material,packagingCount,stock,location,popularity,inStock,categories);"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

mysql -uroot -pbin --show-warnings --execute="..."

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help: [How does one list warnings from the 'mysqlimport' utility?](https://serverfault.com/questions/96401/how-does-one-list-warnings-from-the-mysqlimport-utility)